# How reliable is _CrtCheckMemory?

Tags: c++, qt, heap-memory, heap-corruption

I have some strange heap corruption, and trying to discover it using _CrtCheckMemory.

**If a _CrtCheckMemory function returns true, does it mean 100% that the memory* is fine?**

I think it's obvious when it returns false, then something gone wrong in the memory.

The relevant code is:

```
assert( _CrtCheckMemory() );
renderText( x + (max_height/4.0) * w, y + (fm.descent() + (label.shadedText ? 1.0 : 0.0)) * h, 0.0, label.text, label.font );
assert( _CrtCheckMemory() );
```

The first call returns true, but the second one returns false.
renderText is a QGLWidget::renderText call, and label is a valid object before and after renderText has been called.

*: i mean the heap

Comment: Why are you convinced that the corruption is not occurring inside of the `renderText` function?

Comment: Because the first call of '_CrtCheckMemory' returns true, meaning the heap is fine, and the second one returns false. Between the two heap checks there is the renderText function only.
Although this theory is based on the reliability of _CrtCheckMemory.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, _Crt... debug functions work great, but are lighweight and thus not foolproof. You should push the test inside fm.descent()

Comment: fm.descent() is a member of QFontMetricsF. So I don't have control over it, but tried what you said in a different approach. Replaced fm.descent call with a constant, and still the problem remains.
I am thinking about reporting this to Qt, but i am not sure whether it is really their issue, or I made some mistake..

Comment: maybe label.text contains exotic encoded text or escaped chars, like newlines? How about replacing label.text with a literal, like "test". If this still fails, your last chance will be to report to Qt developers...

Comment: The funny part in this, that there are special characters to display, but they are displayed fine, this particularly happens when a simple "Th. 2.6" string needs to be rendered. 

I think you're right, I'll report it to Qt. Thanks for the feedback. :)

Comment: If anyone interested or encountered the same, I reported this to Qt.
You can track down at this link: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-26649